# Get results from first table even if it's missing data. Right Join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One has a list of all tournaments that are running, and the other has all the scores for those tournaments.

[image]

I have written a query to return all the id's and end_dates for tournaments that have ended (end_time <= now) and where all the scores for that tournament have been verified (equal to 1).

```
SELECT rt.id, rt.difficulty
FROM scores s JOIN running_tournaments rt
ON s.tourn_id = rt.id WHERE end_time <= NOW()
GROUP BY rt.id having min(s.verified) = 1
```

This query works if there is at least 1 score in the tournament.  If the tournament has ended and no scores were entered, nothing is returned by the query.

How can I return results when no scores have been entered in a tournament?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). There is also [support for writing tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support?cb=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You can use `outer join` and use `count` condition in the having claise as follows:

```
SELECT rt.id,
       rt.difficulty 
  FROM scores s 
  RIGHT JOIN running_tournaments rt ON s.tourn_id = rt.id 
  And S.end_time <= NOW() 
GROUP BY RT.ID
having min(s.verified) = 1 or count(s.verified) = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend `LEFT JOIN` -- keep everything in the *first* table -- and reverse the order of the table references:

```
SELECT rt.id, rt.difficulty
FROM running_tournaments rt JOIN
     scores s 
     ON s.tourn_id = rt.id
WHERE end_time <= NOW()
GROUP BY rt.id 
HAVING MIN(s.verified) = 1
```